# redis - include value in new key

Tags: redis, key

How can I include a *value* in a new *key*?

e.g. I create the userId *key* with the *value* 1. Whenever I create a new user, I would like the *key* of the new *value* to include the id, like this: user:[id]

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set userId 1
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> incr userId
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> set user:[userId] name UserName
(error) ERR syntax error
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

What is the syntax for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such syntax - your application logic should fetch the next user ID and set it in the new key.

Note: you don't have to initialize the id key - Redis will treat a non-existing key as 0 by default.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple

Connect to Redis cli using following cmd

```
redis-cli
```

For setting redis key value

```
"SETEX" keynamee ttl value
"SETEX" "userId" "600"  "1"
```

For Getting the value

```
"GET" keyname

"GET" userId
```

You can monitor redis using followin command
    redis-cli monitor

it should work